# should this be two database tables or one?

Tags: sql, database, database-schema

I have a database table called `interviews` and the interviewer and the interviewee will both have to review how the interview went. The review will have similar fields (rating on a scale) but different questions.

Option 1 is to have them both in the same table and have it be `1..N` back to the interview table (storing the ID of the writer and the one being reviewed as well). and only limiting which fields can be input at the application level.

Option 2 is to have two tables (one specifically for interviewer reviews and one specifically for interviewee reviews.

What is your opinion of the best way to model this?

Answer (score 0):

Although this is dangerously close to being opinion-based, I have a comment that is too long for comments.

Handling surveys is rather complicated.  Surveys change over time because questions are added, removed, and modified and answers are added, removed, and modified.  And yet, people often want to use survey questions and track the results over time.

So, the data model for a survey is much more complicated than "one table" or "two tables".  There are tables for surveys, questions, answers, and the relationships and values can change over time.

Comment: Hey Gordon, I think you're right. The thing is (for me) the properties and logic WILL change in the future). I think it's better to start separate frm the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

One big table is often a poor choice. If you index properly and write fine tuned queries, they are going to perform fine. Having multiple table can help you in multiple ways like

Access particular data ,
Easy queries etc

Answer (score 0):

**Two review tables**. Those are TWO bona fide separate entities.

Here's the deal:

- Designing a single table that "works" for two different purposes can be done but it's challenging: on the database level, and on your application.
- But then... a few months later new requirements come in, that makes it more challenging. You'll need to implement weird logic to keep using one table. Code becomes convoluted, and testing becomes a nightmare.
- And then, more changes come in. It becomes unmanageable. At some point you'll realise they were different things from the start that will EVOLVE differently.

Bottom line, it's better to keep them separate from the start to avoid huge cost in the future. Even if they have near-identical columns in the beginning.